# Is it possible to update a textarea-element with data from an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the .ready(function) that I wish to attach to a textarea. Hope you can help me.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(e) {

        $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});

        setInterval(function() {
            $('#chatlogs').load('logs.php');
        }, 2000);

    });  //to display all the reviews

</script>

<textarea name="" style="width:100px; height:100px"></textarea>
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it :/

Comment: "that i wish to put insde a textarea": this part of your question doesn't make sense. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: hello Hashem , the output of that function is evo92: Good !
mod: hello  bob: hello!  but i wish to put inside a textarea or style in

Comment: hello urbz , is it possible to style a document.ready() ?

Comment: I guess that you want to limit the height of the chat area by adding a vertical scrollbar. If so you could specify an explicit `height` for `#chatlogs` and add `overflow-y: auto;`. You may have fallen into a [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: textarea.ready( function(){ ... }); ????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a textarea to display the contents of `logs.php`, and update every 2 seconds. I think this should do it:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get('logs.php', function(data) { 
            $('#chatlogs').text(data);
        });
    }, 2000);
});

</script>

<textarea name="" id="chatlogs" style="width:100px; height:100px"></textarea>
```

Note you also need to add `id="chatlogs"` to your `textarea` for this to work. Let me know in the comments if you need more help.

Comment: hello , erm i try it , it just a normal textarea inside is blank

Comment: Have you included jQuery on your page? You need to paste this in your `head` tag: `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>`

Comment: which should i include ? <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I wonder: Wouldn't it be nicer to use `setTimeout();` on success after each call instead of an interval? Let's say an answer to a request is delayed for whatever reasons, the whole display could go wrong. With a timeout it would be guaranteed that the previous answer got through.

Comment: thanks for those who really trying to help me . really appreciate it

Comment: Sounds like you already had jquery included on the page, so you don't need to include it again. We need to find out if there's an error. Which web browser are you testing this in? Is there a web address to this page somewhere online that I can see?